# Can shutdown.exe be made to show success?

Tags: windows

I use shutdown.exe to reboot a bunch of computers remotely. If it fails, I'm shown the error by doing a 2>&1 redirect to a log file. However, I would like to be shown successes as well, but shutdown.exe doesn't do that. It shows nothing if it succeeds. Is there any way to make it do that?

Comment: What I do is timestamp / echo the computer name to a log file as well as the redirection you mentioned above. If nothing happens I just see the timestamp/name in the log. If it errors out I see the timestamp/name and the error below it. If you wanted to generate a success message you could read the output and then put some conditionals in to echo messages, or, move over to PowerShell (which IMO is way more powerful /better for scripting) and use the stop-computer cmdlet. If you're satisfied with my timestamp/name solution I could post that as an answer though, let me know...

Comment: Keep in mind, a computer that shuts down can't execute any commands due to the shutdown sequence. So normally you would need to create something that triggers after the reboot is completed. For example a scheduled task or simple startup script that writes to the log: "computer logged in succesfully". Also, the event viewer will have logs for the restart and login that can be checked, and using `net statistics workstation` you can see how long the computer is turned on to find out if it restarted.

Comment: @LPChip, like I said, this is a remote execution that I want logged, not on the actual client machine.

Comment: @BrianC, good idea, will do that. I would deem your comment as an actual answer but I don't see how I can mark it so.

Comment: If it is a remote machine, you could in theory issue the shutdown command, get the output and store it in a variable, and check if the variable has anything in it. If it has, it went wrong, if not, it was succesful, and that can be written to the log. Also, check to see if %ERRORLEVEL% is set after the command. Errorlevel 0 = success, anything else is a warning or error.

Comment: @LPChip, the shutdown.exe command itself will print the error if one occurs and nothing if it succeeds. So I can just "assume" it succeeded if no error was generated.

Comment: yes it will print to the screen, but it will also set an environmental variable called errorlevel. Every program does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is timestamp / echo the computer name to a log file as well as the redirection you mentioned in your question. If nothing happens I just see the timestamp/name in the log. If it errors out I see the timestamp/name and the error below it. For example, here is an excerpt from a generated log (names obfuscated into generic computer names):

```
-- START BATCH - Wed 04/12/2017 -  0:15:25.88 -- 

COMPUTER1 - Wed 04/12/2017 -  0:15:26.90 

COMPUTER2 - Wed 04/12/2017 -  0:15:29.53 

COMPUTER3 - Wed 04/12/2017 -  0:15:32.20 
COMPUTER3: The entered computer name is not valid or remote shutdown is not supported on the target computer. Check the name and then try again or contact your system administrator.(53)

COMPUTER4 - Wed 04/12/2017 -  0:15:36.59 

 (etc)...

-- END BATCH - Thu 04/13/2017 -  0:20:21.04 --
```

As you can see, COMPUTER3 had an error, which was directed from STDERR to STDOUT. Everything else accepted the command without issue.

Here is the actual batch file driving all of that, which reads computer names from a text file called COMPUTERS.txt and dumps into a log called LOG_COMPUTERS.txt. I run it as a scheduled task with elevated rights, but you could run it on demand / on its own without issue. Whichever account runs the batch file will need administrative rights on the remote PC.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo. >> LOG_COMPUTERS.txt
echo -- START BATCH - !date! - !time! -- >> LOG_COMPUTERS.txt

for /f %%i in (COMPUTERS.txt) do (
echo %%i - !date! - !time! >> LOG_COMPUTERS.txt
shutdown.exe /s /f /m \\%%i /t 300 /c "This PC will shut down in 5 minutes.  Please save all of your work." >> LOG_COMPUTERS.txt 2>&1
echo. >> LOG_COMPUTERS.txt
)

echo. >> LOG_COMPUTERS.txt
echo -- END BATCH - !date! - !time! -- >> LOG_COMPUTERS.txt
```

It's crude but it has worked very well for a long time...